# Calculating class attendance (Ch 1 Problem 39 Intro to Probability)

Tags: probability

This is Problem 1.39 from Tsitsiklis, Bertsekas, Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition.

[question-alt-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/untx5.png)

My answer was $P(A) = W (P_g * k) + W^c (P_b * k)$

where W is the probability of good weather and k is the number of students required for the class to be taught.

The solution book says it is

[solution-alt-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcaj7.png)

My thinking is that:

-Each student chooses independently whether to go to class

-They have $P_g$ given good weather and $P_b$ given bad weather

-The multiplication rule says you can calculate many independent events by the probability of each event * the number of events

Why doesn't the multiplication rule apply?

Comment: Any idea how to make the images appear inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit incorrect.

> Multiplication rule says that: total probability is **not** probability of each event multiplied by number of events, but rather, probabilities of all individual events multiplied together.

You wrote $$P(A)=W(P_g*k)+W^c(P_b*k)$$ 
But, since event that one particular student turns up is independent of other, you have a probability of $P_g$ or $P_b$ for each one of those k students; so, it is not $P_g*k$, but rather, $P_g^k$ and $P_b^k$.

So, it would reduce to $$P(A)=W(P_g^k)+W^c(P_b^k)$$

But wait. We need to select k students out of n and then find total probability, which will be:
**P(prof teaches)=P(teaches when weather is good) + P(teaches when weather is bad)**

Hint:

Do you know conditional probability?
Use $$P(teaches) = P(bad)P(teaches/bad) + P(good)P(teaches/good)$$
That summation shown in P(A/B) and P(A/$B^c$) step is used to include all possibilities of no. of students turning up for a given weather, whose iteration begins from i=k because prof needs at least k students out of n for lecture.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can you help shed light on why the book gives a different answer?

Comment: bcoz we need to select k students out of n...which we missed.

Comment: why can't you use total probability and say P(A) = $\sum_{n=1}^k P(W) * P(P_g)$

Comment: edited, do you understand now?

Comment: Why do we need to count the students who don't come? If this is a coin toss, the problem says we need k tosses to be heads. Their probability counts the likelihood of k - n tails * k heads. Why include the tails?

Comment: bcoz there are n students, we need an outcome for all of them. Eg. when there are 2 black, 3 red balls and you want 3,at least 1 being black. dont you take cases like 2B1R,1B2R? did we ignore red balls?

Comment: if a student comes,then Pg or Pb. if not then, (1-Pg) or (1-Pb) respectively. Dont just ignore non-comers...